# Return Array for each column (one query command)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-10

This is my People table, and I'm looking to get one array for each column as output.

| name | surname |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 5 |
| Cell 3 | Null |

```
SELECT array_agg(name) AS names FROM people
```

I only understand how to return one array from the table, but I would like to have one array for each column without any expression (comparing).

Im looking for a Result like this below:

`((Cell1, Cell2, Cell3), (Cell4, Cell5))`

It would be also fine to use different Tables instead of Columns.
So turning two Queries below, into one

```
SELECT array_agg(name) FROM name
SELECT array_agg(surname) FROM surname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all : `((Cell1, Cell2, Cell3), (Cell4, Cell5))` is not the right notation for a sql array.

`{{Cell1, Cell2, Cell3}, {Cell4, Cell5}}` is the right notation for a text array but you will get the sql error *"Multidimensional arrays must have sub-arrays with matching dimensions"* because the first sub-array is of dimension 3 whereas the second sub-array is of dimension 2, which is not accepted for sql arrays.

So you have two solutions here :

**Solution 1** : including NULL values so that both sub-arrays have the same dimension :

```
SELECT array(SELECT array_agg(name) FROM people_table UNION ALL SELECT array_agg(surname) FROM people_table) ;
```

The result is of type `text[]` :

| array |
| --- |
| {{"Cell 1","Cell 2","Cell 3"},{"Cell 4","Cell 5",NULL}} |

**Solution 2** : replacing the sql array by a `json` array which accepts sub-arrays with various dimensions while excluding the `NULL` values for the `surname` column :

```
SELECT json_build_array(array_agg(name), array_agg(surname) FILTER (WHERE surname IS NOT NULL)) AS array FROM people_table ;
```

The result is of type `json` :

| array |
| --- |
| [["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"], ["Cell 4", "Cell 5"]] |

Last but not least, when name and surname come from two different tables :

```
-- warning: both sub queries must return the same number of rows !
SELECT array(SELECT array_agg(name) FROM name UNION ALL SELECT array_agg(surname) FROM surname) ;
```

or

```
-- notice: both sub queries may return different numbers of rows
SELECT json_build_array((SELECT to_json(array_agg(name)) FROM name), (SELECT to_json(array_agg(surname)) FROM surname WHERE surname IS NOT NULL)) AS array  ;
```